# a (javascript) countdown that doesn't restart at page refresh?

Tags: javascript, countdown

i was wondering if there is any solution for implementing a javascript counter that doesn't reset at page refreshm but it continues counting until the set time passes.

What do you know about it?

thank you

Comment: Store the countdown end date somewhere, either in a cookie or write it into the page on the server side. Who determines the countdown end - the client or the server?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could store the current countdown timer count in a cookie (you would do that every time the timer changes). And then when the page loads (or refreshes) check for the value of that cookie first, and if it is set use that value as the starting point of the countdown counter.

Answer (score 2):

You will need to store its state somewhere, either in a cookie or serverside.

On each page load, the code will need to check its state and adjust its countdown accordingly.

Answer (score 2):

You can use localStorage or cookies to store your current counter value.
Here's an example: http://jsfiddle.net/ArtBIT/KsYE4/

Comment: In this example, you are storing the counter, you should be storing the target data. Right now, when you refresh the page, it goes to what it was before the page was reloaded, even if it took 20 seconds to reload. That is, if the counter was at 30, and it takes 10 seconds to refresh, is should then be at 20